# Editing XML using a php script

Tags: php, xml, file, editing

I have a problem, I need to edit an xml file using php, based on a string variable it has been passed.

i.e., my php has a string variable which takes the value of either "true" or "false" and I need to alter the following xml file code:

```
<Parameter>             
     <ParameterName>Method1</ParameterName>                  
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription>
     <ParameterValue type="bool">false</ParameterValue>
</Parameter>

<Parameter> 
     <ParameterName>Method2</ParameterName>       
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription> 
     <ParameterValue type="bool">true</ParameterValue>
</Parameter> 

<Parameter>
     <ParameterName>Method3</ParameterName>
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription>
     <ParameterValue type="float">0.025</ParameterValue> 
</Parameter>
```

So that the first "ParameterValue" changes from it's default "false" to whatever the value of the variable is (note that the variable in the php is a string, and in the xml is a boolean type). I have looked at suggestions involving awk, and sen and dom without much luck. I am hoping for the simplest way to change this one word in the XML!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making things too complicated. XML is just a string (text file) that has some formatiing requirements. Just create the string as any other but bear in mind those formatting rules.

This should do the trick in PHP.

```
$xml = <<<EOT
<Parameter>              
     <ParameterName>Method1</ParameterName>                   
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription>
EOT

$xml .= '     <ParameterValue type="bool">' . $var . "false</ParameterValue>\n";
$xml .= <<<EOT;
</Parameter> 

<Parameter>  
     <ParameterName>Method2</ParameterName>        
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription>  
     <ParameterValue type="bool">true</ParameterValue> 
</Parameter>  

<Parameter> 
     <ParameterName>Method3</ParameterName> 
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription> 
     <ParameterValue type="float">0.025</ParameterValue>  
</Parameter> 
EOT;
```

You can then save the string to file (adding the other XML stuff that is required!), print it to STDOUT or load it into DOMDocument for further processing. Your choice.

Comment: Ok, the xml file already exists, is there no better way of just changing one word in it, I don't want to have to re-write the whole text in the php........ If I do have to do the above, how do I save it over an already existing file? Sorry I am very new to PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Domdocument class? http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php with this class, you could edit your XML

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to us dom in php if it's not really necessary...

for instance writing a document from scratch can be done without dom.

Even if you don't use Dom php, be careful with encoding, if you need to use the generated file after with dom... then put appropriate xml headers... (without it it's really @*!§&)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple xml libraries in php, including [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [Dom](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).
For selecting nodes, both library supports xpath which is a powerfull tool.
With Dom this would look like something like this:

```
$the_variable = true;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$elements = $xml->xpath('//Parameter/ParameterValue[text()="false"]'); // select paramter/parameterValue nodes where the text content is "false"
foreach ($elements as $elem) {
    $elem[0] = $the_variable; // will output "<ParameterValue>1</ParameterValue>"
    // $elem[0] = var_export($the_variable, true); // will output "<ParameterValue>true</ParameterValue>"
}   

print $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: So if the variable is a string, but the type is a boolean in the xml, what do I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what the connection between you xml document and the php variables. In the end you every variable you place into the `$elem[type]` or `$elem[0]` will be converted to string according to php's [string conversions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

Comment: <ParameterName>Method1</ParameterName>                  
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription>
     <ParameterValue type="bool">false</ParameterValue>

Comment: Changed to <ParameterName>Method1</ParameterName>                  
     <ParameterDescription>description</ParameterDescription>
     <ParameterValue type="bool">$variable</ParameterValue>

Comment: I've updated the xpath query to select only ParameterValues whith "false" in them. You can fiddle with the selection or the node manipulatinon to get your desired result.

Comment: Ah thankyou! Unfortunately I want this file to be continuously overwritten, so the second time of running this value could be true and need changing back to false if you see what I mean.........